# System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Grid exists twice in GAC

Tags: asp.net, gac, mschart

I've upgraded a web application from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4, and I get this exception when browsing to a page that uses the Chart control:

> The type 'System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Grid' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DataVisualization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__...\System.Web.DataVisualization.dll' and 'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DataVisualization\3.5.0.0__...\System.Web.DataVisualization.dll'

How can I get this working, using the 4.0 control?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [assembly redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx).

For example (make sure the `publicKeyToken` is correct, I don't have the assembly on this computer):

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.DataVisualization"
                              publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"
                              culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.5.0.0"
                             newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4):

1) Upgrade all references that point to the 3.5 Chart control in web.config to reference version 4:

```
tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" ... Version=4.0.0.0 ...

add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" ... Version=4.0.0.0 ...

add name="ChartImageHandler" ... Version=4.0.0.0 ...
```

2) Remove all charting libs from your Bin directory because they are already included in the .NET 4 framework

Answer (score 0):

Remove one of them , one is in the GAC and one is in your project i guees.

Maybe you have a reference in your project that is left after you used. NET 3.5? Or other DLLs that use it: =)